# solution for writing query

Tags: sql

I have a match table with winningteamid and stadiumid as attributes,
I need to retrieve the winningteamid which has won all its games in the same stadium.

I tried this, and I'm getting additional unwanted rows:

```
select winningteamid 
from match
group by winningteamid
having count(winningteamid) in (
    select count(*) from match group by (winningteamid,stadiumid)
```

Comment: Syntax error...

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as well formatted text.

Answer (score 0):

You should use this:

```
SELECT MAX(winningteamid)
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT winningteamid, stadiumid
    FROM match 
)
GROUP BY stadiumid
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1;
```

Comment: I am using oracle

Answer (score 0):

Try this please (please write which RDBMS you are using):

```
with cte as (
    select winningteamid, stadiumid, count(stadiumid) over (partition by winningteamid) as count
    from match
    group by winningteamid, stadiumid
)
select * from cte where count = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you.. Working well

Comment: you are welcome, please vote or accept the answer if this was the solution

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it's as easy as using `HAVING` to verify only one distinct stadiumid:

```
select winningteamid 
from match
group by winningteamid
having count(distinct stadiumid) = 1
```

Comment: I am using oracle 9i,    match tables with attributes matchid, winningteamid, stadiumid